# Is it possible to view the entire search history in Google Maps and not just the most recent one?

Tags: google-maps

If you press in the text box to type address in Google Maps, it only shows the few recent searches. This initially made be believe it deletes older searches. However if you type one or a few letters it does do an autocomplete from the past searches (with the history icon next to the address), which means that it does save the entire search history.

So I wonder if there's a way to view the entire the search history without having to resort to the autocomplete function?